# How am I receiving a exception?

Tags: rpc

```
swap_tx.recent_blockhash = http_client.get_latest_blockhash(commitment=Commitment("confirmed")).value.blockhash
swap_tx.sign(wallet, Wsol_account_keyPair)
http_client.send_raw_transaction(swap_tx.serialize(),opts=TxOpts(max_retries=0))
```

I am getting: solana.rpc.core.RPCException: SendTransactionPreflightFailureMessage { message: "Transaction simulation failed: Blockhash not found", data: RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(BlockhashNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }

How is that possible if I just got the blockhash?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but you could have been talking to two different nodes that were at different heights.

For example, you received a blockhash from an RPC node at slot 110, but the RPC node that received your transaction was at 109, so it wasn't aware of that blockhash yet.

This can happen sometimes unfortunately -- if it fails with this error, feel free to retry your transaction or use an older blockhash commitment like "finalized".